# Bootstrap адаптивное оформление

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, bootstrap

### Как сделать чтобы объекты 1 2 и 3 заполняли всю высоту div2

*,но не на равные три части нужно чтобы 1 и 3 были равны а 2 я выставлял бы сам?*

---

Примерно вот так:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*проблема в том что Div2 занимает весь экран и я не могу знать его высоту.*

---

**Важно что бы я мог выставлять высоту 2 произвольно например вот так:**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на flex это делается ...http://html5.by/blog/flexbox/

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, ну тут человек опять хочет чтобы за него решили задачу) Уже ж второй вопрос, а кода так и нет.

Comment: @Elena уж полночь близится, а кода так и нет.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Ну вот я бы не сказал что ответ очень уж очевиден. Особенно учитывая что решение по-хорошему должно быть кроссбраузерным (хоть как-то стоит учитывать поделки дядюшки Билла и хотя бы с запасом на 5 версий FF и Chrome) Если у вас есть решение, я бы тоже посмотрел

Comment: @Elena я новичок на стаке я не знаю как отредактировать вопрос)Но Большое спасибо за ответ на первый вы очень помогли

Comment: @Филиппстраченко, да нет за что. Отредактировать вопрос - http://prntscr.com/eoobpj

Comment: @Elena  глупо получилось могу ли я связаться как то с вами дабы уточнить ваше решение?

Comment: @Филиппстраченко, в комментариях пишите тут или к ответу http://prntscr.com/eooe9u

Comment: @Elena я имел ввиду соц.сети например Whatsapp

Comment: @VipFilStar, лучше тут. Потому как возможно я не смогу помочь, но кто-то поймет ваш вопрос, комментарии и даст верное решение.

Comment: @Elena быть может все таки оставите whatsapp

Comment: @VipFilStar, не пользуюсь whatsapp

Comment: @Elena ну так что нибудь

Comment: @Elena отлично я напишу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не уверена что условие поняла, но например [flex](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex):

```css
body {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #95989a;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.div2 {
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.b-1,
.b-3 {
  background: #ffb9b9;
  
  /*height: 100px;*/
}

.b-2 {
  background: #ffdcdc;
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100vh; /* На всю высоту экрана, например */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-1">
      1
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-2">
      2
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Вариант 2 (задана фиксированная высота второго блока):

```css
body {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #95989a;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.div2 {
  background: #dfdfdf;
}

.b-1,
.b-3 {
  background: #ffb9b9;
  
  /* height: 100px; */
  flex: 1 auto;
}

.b-2 {
  background: #ffdcdc;
  /* flex: 1 auto; */
  height: 50px;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100vh; /* На всю высоту экрана, например */
  
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-1">
      1
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-2">
      2
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-offset-5 col-xs-2 b-3">
      3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А как решен вопрос с произвольной высотой второго блока? Допустим он должен быть высотой 50px

Comment: @tutankhamun, ну вот тут то и непонятно мне. Я так подумала, что высота неизвестна из-за содержимого. если во втором будет текст, то 1 и 3 блок будут одинаковой высоты .

Comment: @Elena не из-за содержимого я имел ввиду произвольный ввод высоты 2 блока (у меня тот же вопрос что и у Тутанхамона)

Comment: @VipFilStar, добавила вариант если задана фиксированная высота второго блока.

Comment: Хотя соглашусь, что решение не идеальное, это, всего лишь, как вариант